# Javascript: using brackets in alpacajs form name fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel, alpacajs

I'm trying to create a multiple select field with this output:

```
<select id="alpaca41" multiple="multiple" name="metrics[]" class="alpaca-control form-control"></select>
```

The brackets in the name are important, beceause it tells laravel that this form field returns multiple values.

When I give the alapaca form fields a name with brackets in the JSON alpaca config, they wont show in the HTML. The brackets are transformed to an underscore. This is the result:

```
<select id="alpaca41" multiple="multiple" name="metrics_" class="alpaca-control form-control"></select>
```

Replacing the brackets with ASCII code wont do the trick. :(

So my question: how do you get brackets in alpaca form fields?

Comment: I am really not sure but did you try "metrics\[\]"  ?

Comment: If I edit the name in the DOM to "metrics[]", it works meaning that Laravel detects the multiple select and returns an array. If I input "metrics[]" in the JSON structure for Alpacaforms, Alpaca transforms it to an underscore so I suspect it to be a problem with the JS lib.

Comment: which version of alpaca are you using? because I have a working example here with brackets in the name of field. can you take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/5xjtkcg2/.

Comment: Thank you very-very-very mutch vert3x. First, I added the name field in the schema section and not in the options section like you did. Now I've changed that, and it solved the problem. If you repost the answer, I can give you an upvote for solving it (if you want lol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given by @vert3x in the comments of the original post. The name field was used in the `schema` section and not in the `options` section.

http://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/5xjtkcg2/